# How to have a function return several different type Eigen matrixes (C++)

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to call a function that allocates, compute, and then returns to the calling function several Eigen matrixes.

The output size of each matrix is not known before hand, ergo we cannot allocate such matrices in the calling function.

Here is what I though was the way (passing Matrices in by Ref class, and resize inside):

```
FromImageToAb(image, 
Eigen::Ref<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> Aout, Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd> bout){

    ... // determine what size matrixes must have: int equationcounter, numberofunknowns

    // Allocate matrixes of the correct size
    SparseMatrix<double> A(equationcounter, numberofunknowns);
    SparseMatrix<double> bM(equationcounter, 1);

    ... // fill A and bM 

    VectorXd b(bM); // Now we have successfully created a dense vector of the correct size that cannot be known before hand

    Aout = A;
    bout = b;
}


main(){
    SparseMatrix<double> Aout(1,1); // Creating matrix with token size
    VectorXd bout(1); // Creating matrix with token size
    FromImageToAb(image, Aout, bout);

}
```

but `Aout = A;` doesn't allocate memory and copy the values so it's usable outside
and `bout = b;` doesn't compile, as dense matrices cannot be resized to increase memory

What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Your function doesn't take any parameter _by reference_, also there's a return type (at least `void`) missing from the definition.

Comment: "... returns to the calling function several Eigen matrixes..." - So, return a `std::vector` of matrices. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: Because the matrices will be of different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not **return** a value that contains both?

```
std::tuple<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::VectorXd> FromImageToAb(image_t image)
{
    ... // determine what size matrixes must have: int equationcounter, numberofunknowns

    // Allocate matrixes of the correct size
    SparseMatrix<double> A(equationcounter, numberofunknowns);
    SparseMatrix<double> bM(equationcounter, 1);

    ... // fill A and bM 

    return { a, bM }; // Uses implicit conversion of SparseMatrix<double> -> VectorXd
}
```

If you have a C++17 compiler, you can avoid default constructing the values with [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

```
int main(){
    auto [a, b] = FromImageToAb(image);
    // use a and b
}
```

Otherwise you can assign multiple things with [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

```
int main(){
    SparseMatrix<double> a; // Default construct
    VectorXd b; // Default construct
    std::tie(a, b) = FromImageToAb(image);
    // use a and b
}
```

Comment: What happens here memory wise. A and bM are copied out correct? In C++, is there a easy-to-code-and-read-way to allocate memory inside a function and have it live after the function ends?

Comment: @WurmD before C++17 copy elision would *most likely* mean nothing expensive would happen, post C++17 it is *guaranteed*